# primefaces datatable is not getting refresh in tab

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, tabs, accordion

I have one problem, data is not getting refresh in datatable.I am opening a dialoge box in which I have accordian panel in acordian panel I have tab in tab I have datatable.

```
<p:dialog id="dlgAddEditFundsCustFinAcct"               
                widgetVar="dlgAddEditFundsCustFinAcctWidget" modal="true"
'
.
<p:accordionPanel id="accAEFCFA" widgetVar="accWidget">
    <p:tab id="tabDocuments" widgetVar="tabDocumentsWidget">
<p:panel id="pnlDocuments" widgetVar="pnlDocumentsWidget" >
<p:panelGrid id="pgDocumentTable" columns="5">
<p:dataTable id="dtDocumentTable" var="documentRecord" value="#addEditFundsCustFinAcctManagedBean.documentDetails}"         widgetVar="documentTable">
```

And I have properly close all the tab.

And I am trying to call this dialogue box using

```
<p:commandButton value="Yes" styleClass="button-green"
 id="btnAddSellerAccountSsr"                    oncomplete="confirmAccountDialog.hide(),dlgAddEditFundsCustFinAcctWidget.show()"    update=":parentForm:dlgAddEditFundsCustFinAcct" />
```

"parentForm" is my form name.

The one thing is that if I call update inside the  on some event like filtering on column or on rowclick then data is getting refresh in datatable.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <p:commandButton value="Yes" styleClass="button-green" id="btnAddSellerAccountSsr" 
    oncomplete="confirmAccountDialog.hide(),dlgAddEditFundsCustFinAcctWidget.show()"    
    update="dtDocumentTable" >
        <f:ajax render="dtDocumentTable"/>
    </p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Please elaborate in technical developer's terms how exactly the problem is caused and how exactly this piece of code solves it, instead of making it a completely unhelpful Search&Find game.

Answer (score 0):

use two forms. one for dialog box and other for parentform, and then update dialogbox datatable using its id

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Saurabh and Zaido.

Unfortunatly both solution has not worked for me. 
But I have solved the issue by calling clearfilter methode of datatable (this is client side methode).

```
<p:commandButton value="Yes" styleClass="button-green" id="btnAddSellerAccountSsr" 
    oncomplete="confirmAccountDialog.hide(),**documentTable.clearFilters();"**
    update="dtDocumentTable" >
        <f:ajax render="dtDocumentTable"/>
    </p:commandButton>
```

where documentTable is widgetVar of datatable.

Hope this solution will help any one who has same issue :)

Comment: I am facing the same issue but not able to fix it. Can you help me?